# Python regex - any substring matches

Tags: python, regex

I want to find dates in the formats `18-05-2018` **and** `18-05-18`, but **not** `2018-05-18`. I want to use regular expressions such that I get `True` when such a date appears in a string.

So it should return `True` for these strings:

- `ggggg18-05-2018ggggg`
- `ggggg18-05-2018ggggg12345678`
- `ggggg18-05-18ggggg`
- `ggggg18-05-18ggggg12345678`

But it should return `False` for these strings:

- `ggggg2018-05-18ggggg`
- `ggggg2018-05-18ggggg12345678`

How to do it? I've found `findall()` method and pattern `'\d{1,2}[-]\d{1,2}[-]\d{2,4}'` but it returned `True` for the last two strings, as it found `18-05-18` in them.

Comment: What should it return for e.g. `2018-12-12-12` or `01.01.01-01-01`? And what for strings that contain dates for both formats like `ggg18-05-18gggg2018-05-18ggg`?

Comment: It should return true if there is even one that matches the pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use *negative* lookbehind and lookahead:

```
import re

s = 'sasdassdsadasdadas18-05-2018sdaq1213211214142'

print(re.findall(r'(?<!\d)\d{1,2}[-]\d{1,2}[-]\d{2,4}(?!\d)', s))
# ['18-05-2018']
```

This makes sure that there is no trailing digits at the beginning or at the end of what is desired.

---

To prove that it handles your error case:

```
import re

s = 'sasdassdsadasdadas2018-05-2018sdaq1213211214142'

print(re.findall(r'(?<!\d)\d{1,2}[-]\d{1,2}[-]\d{2,4}(?!\d)', s))
# []
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to check that what comes before the start of the date match is either a non number of the start of the input, and that what comes after the date match is also a non digit or the end of the input.

```
text = "sasdassdsadasdadas18-05-2018sdaq1213211214142"
matches = re.findall(r'(?:\D|^)(\d{1,2}[-]\d{1,2}[-]\d{2,4})(?:\D|$)', text)
print matches

['18-05-2018']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a negative lookbehind `(?<!...)`, which you can insert at any point in a regular expression to ensure that whatever comes right before that point does *not* match a certain expression (the `...`). In your case, you want to ensure that what comes right before the beginning of the expression doesn't match a digit (`\d`), so you would insert `(?<!\d)` at the beginning of your regex.

If you would also like to exclude matches with the wrong number of digits at the end, as in `aaaa18-05-181bbb`, then you could also use a negative lookahead `(?!...)`, which is similar to the negative lookbehind except that it ensures whatever comes *after* a certain point does not match an expression. In your case, to ensure that a digit does not come after the end of the match, you'd add `(?!\d)` at the end of your expression.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a negative lookbehind and a negative lookahead to assert that there are no digits on the left and on the right side. To match either 2 or 4 digits at the end you could use an alternation:

`(?<!\d)\d{2}-\d{2}-(?:\d{4}|\d{2})(?!\d)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IMuBvP/1/)

```
import re
str = 'ggggg18-05-2018ggggg12345678'
print(re.findall(r'(?<!\d)\d{2}-\d{2}-(?:\d{4}|\d{2})(?!\d)', str))
```

Note that you can use the hyphen without the character class.

[Demo Python](https://ideone.com/yXYRjl)